# Cannot write to '-' (Broken pipe) OVH server?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wget

I am trying to run this command to install Windows on my OVH VPS and I get Cannot write to '-' (Broken pipe);

```
root@rescue-pro:~# sudo -i wget -O- 'http://mirror.joodle.nl/Windows_Server2012R2.gz' | gunzip | dd of=/dev/sda
sudo: unable to resolve host rescue-pro
--2016-03-21 17:12:02--  http://mirror.joodle.nl/Windows_Server2012R2.gz
Resolving mirror.joodle.nl (mirror.joodle.nl)... 37.187.16.147
Connecting to mirror.joodle.nl (mirror.joodle.nl)|37.187.16.147|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 4988552803 (4.6G) [application/x-gzip]
Saving to: `STDOUT'

 0% [                                                               ] 0           --.-K/s              dd: writing to `/dev/sda': No space left on device
20481+0 records in
20480+0 records out
10485760 bytes (10 MB) copied, 0.276175 s, 38.0 MB/s
 0% [                                                               ] 1,517,197   7.80M/s   in 0.2s    


Cannot write to `-' (Broken pipe).
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to superuser.com. Although the problem/issue is very clear, the wget command is not able to write, you should express exactly that in words yourself so that all that reads your question, including those that does not know your operating system and commands also can read, understand and maybe give good recommendations without knowing specific OS and command details.

Answer (score 0):

`wget` is returning the error about sending the output to STDOUT.  Try `curl` instead of `wget`:

```
# curl 'http://mirror.joodle.nl/Windows_Server2012R2.gz' | gunzip | dd of=/dev/sda bs=1M
```

`curl` normally writes to STDOUT.

Answer (score 0):

wget complains about a broken pipe output. The error find its origin in the pipe : `| gunzip | dd of=/dev/sda`

It could either be from a gunzip error, or from a dd error. In your example, the sudo command is applied to wget, not to the following pipe. So, dd should fail to write output to /dev/sda, and exit with error. In this condition, the output pipe to wget is stopped by dd exiting and wget complains.

I believe your command line should be:

```
wget -O- 'http://mirror.joodle.nl/Windows_Server2012R2.gz' \
  | gunzip | sudo -i dd of=/dev/sda
```